# Correct attribution is not possible on some websites

Tags: discussion

When posting user content from the Stack Exchange Network onto some other websites, it is not possible to be in compliance with the attribution requirements set forth in the Terms of Service.

Examples include:

- embedded URL's in non-HTML documents, such as source code
- websites that do not allow hyperlinks
- websites that `nofollow` all hyperlinks
- websites that do not allow URL's in non-obfuscated form

Currently user content from the Stack Exchange Network cannot be used on such websites. Is this intentional, or is this a mistake in the Terms of Service? If the latter, does it need to be changed?